# Exception in SharePoint WebApplication

Tags: document-library, session

I have developed a asp.net web application in SharePoint 2010,which deals libraries.I have to redirect the user,so I implemented session state.When I run it I am getting the following exception.

"{"Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \ section in the application configuration."}"

1.In Web.config file , I made the sessionstate = true.The application works fine for a web application but it wont work for another web application on the same SharePoint 
Server farm.i compared both the web.config files ,there is no difference at all.

I don't know why this exception is occured.Please answer this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read Mark Arends blog post on how to enable SessionState in SharePoint 2010
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markarend/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: Hi Anders Thank You very much it works well for me.
Please have a look at my question at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216832/how-to-get-the-absolute-url-of-a-file-in-sharepoint-library